# How to set value in web.xml using property file?

Tags: java, servlets, properties, web.xml

I would like to know if there is possibility to set an attribute in `web.xml` by using property file. For example the web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>Map.MyJNDI</param-name>
  <param-value>java:comp/env/jdbc/${my.computer}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and `application.properties` would be:

```
# My computer's name
my.computer=eniac
```

Comment: Check these: 

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380817/properties-file-as-init-param-in-web-xml
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099008/how-to-include-values-from-properties-file-into-web-xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properties file as init-param in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380817/properties-file-as-init-param-in-web-xml)

Answer (score 2):

you can not set value from `Properties` file but you can set the property file and read its at runtime.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>propfile</param-name>
    <param-value>myproject.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

then read the property file at runtime.

```
MyServlet myServlet = new MyServlet();

Properties  properties = new Properties();
//  get the properties file name 
String propfile = myServlet.getInitParameter("propfile");

// load the file 
properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propfile));

// get the desire properties 
Object propName = properties.get("my.computer");
// out.println(propName.toString());
```

hope this help other too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have values substituted in web.xml like that.

One option I can suggest if possible just have a template web.xml with place holder for values and during build for each environment have a step in build process that will substitute required values from required properties file of that environment.